# Problem while editing YAML/cfg file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, config, configparser

I'm using `configparser` in Python 3 to edit a file -

```
[conf]
users:
 - william
 - bill
 - johnny
```

I want to add another value under `users:`.

My code is as follows-

```
from configparser import SafeConfigParser
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('config5.cfg')
a = parser.get('conf', 'users')
parser.set('conf', 'users', a + ' hank')
with open('config5.cfg', 'w') as f:
    parser.write(f)
```

But instead of -

```
    users:
     - william
     - bill
     - johnny
     - hank
```

It becomes -

```
    users:
     - william
     - bill
     - johnny hank
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the value of user with `parser.get('conf', 'users')`. Then output:

```
'\n- william\n- bill\n- johnny'
```

So you can append new value like that:

```
parser.set('conf', 'users', old + '\n- hank')
```